# mySQL how to select some data in the same field from limit date

Tags: mysql

I got the data from my table with the query

```
SELECT dt, place
FROM horseri
WHERE horseid = 'C299'
AND dt < '20200715'
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

as below, where `dt` is the date and the `place` is the winning place

```
dt         | place
----------------------
2020-07-12 | 8
2020-06-07 | 2
2020-05-17 | 3
2020-04-12 | 9
2020-03-29 | 12
2020-03-01 | 3
2020-02-16 | 4
2020-01-27 | 5
2019-12-18 | 3
2019-11-23 | 10
2019-10-30 | 2
2019-10-01 | 9
2019-09-08 | 2
2019-07-14 | 7
2019-07-01 | 13
2019-06-16 | 7
2019-05-18 | 8
2019-03-31 | 13
2019-03-17 | 12
```

How can I get the first 3 winning places from the data only by the last 10 date ?

My expected output will be

```
dt         | place
----------------------
2020-06-07 | 2
2020-05-17 | 3
2020-03-01 | 3
2019-12-18 | 3
```

Comment: Please include the expected output from the 19 rows of sample data you provided above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for the missing expected output. I have done the question edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the most recent 10 dates. Then select the top 3 places from that.

```
SELECT dt, place
FROM (
    SELECT dt, place
    FROM horseri
    where horseid = 'C299'
    ORDER BY dt DESC
    LIMIT 10
) as x
WHERE place <= 3
```

Comment: thats simple enough. Thank you and is there any possible if i want to isolate the winning places like 1st_palce, 2nd_palce, and 3rd_place with the condition above ?

Answer (score 0):

The more modern way of writing Barmar's answer (assuming it be what the OP wants here), would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT dt, place
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) rn
    FROM horseri
    WHERE horseid = 'C299'
) t
WHERE rn <= 10 AND place <= 3;
```

To isolate individual places, just change the outer `WHERE` clause.  For example, for second place finishers in the most recent 10 dates, use:

```
WHERE rn <= 10 AND place = 2
```

Comment: I have an error running the query near `over (order by dt desc)`

Comment: @KopiBryant Then maybe you are still using MySQL 5.x.  The answer I gave might be the preferred way of writing the query on MySQL 8+ though, so I will leave it up.